# ef core context set from property type

Tags: properties, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, soft-delete

On my project I am doing soft delete (changing to false isActive property and filtering records using EF Core query filter ) for records and I need a way to delete (also soft delete) navigation properties (which can be a reference property or a collection) that I put a attribute to them.

This is the Attribute I wrote for property :

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class DatabaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    bool softDelete;
    public virtual bool SoftDelete
    {
        get { return softDelete; }
        set { softDelete = value; }
    }
}
```

It used :

```cs
public Guid? CargoTransactionId { get; set; }
[Database(SoftDelete = true)]
public CargoTransaction CargoTransaction { get; set; }
```

The Code at below I can find navigation property which I have flagged for soft delete :

```cs
var entries = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
    var entryNavigations = entry.Navigations;
    foreach (var navigation in entryNavigations)
    {
        var dbAttribute = navigation.Metadata.PropertyInfo.CustomAttributes
            .Where(p => p.AttributeType == typeof(DatabaseAttribute))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

bu I could not able to find DbSet entity type to use in context like with the method `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()`.

Can you help with that?

Comment: You use reflection, but this produce inedible code. I don't think you need `DbSet`. Can you explain why it needed?

Comment: the goal I need to achieve is that delete navigation property from database. So I think I need TEntity model type which has DatabaseAttribute custom attribute